# How can i add a picture to my wall post in C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to add a picture to my wall post, Everything is posted on the wall except the picture, I have binded url of the picture to an accessible url but it does show on the wall's post.

my c# code:
 FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(Session["SSAccessToken"].ToString());

```
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "MESSAGE";
            parameters.link = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port+"/Default.aspx?vw=2&Id="+ID;
            **parameters.picture = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + "/Images/Test.jpg";**
            parameters.name = "Title";
            parameters.caption ="Caption"
            parameters.description = "Description...";
            parameters.actions = new
            {
                name = "Contribute",
              // tagret = "_blank",
                link = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port  + "/Contributor.aspx?Id=" + goal.ID
            };
            parameters.privacy = new
            {
                value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
            };
            parameters.targeting = new
            {
                countries = "US",
                regions = "6,53",
                locales = "6",
            };
            dynamic result = app.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

The picture doesnt show on the wall's post ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API Explorer to see how the link is on the wall post:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Make the action on your app that creates a post and verify on the explorer how the picture link looks. If everything is ok, the 'src' parameter will be your image url.

For example, this is how a post from my app looks on the explorer:

```
{
  "id": "100001536253568_310941908967015", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Henrique Baggio", 
    "id": "100001536253568"
  }, 
  "message": "Confirmou presença em um evento", 
  "picture": "http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=193921427300379&v=1&size=z&cksum=2d14ff50fc9a74375400e780d6c46d32&src=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.findparty.com.br\u00252FImages\u00252FEvent\u00252F101\u00253Ftype\u00253Dgo", 
  // other post information
},
```

This way you can check if the link is accessible by the facebook platform.